# Drag and Drop groups to schedule

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, drag-and-drop

To simplify the problem - I have schedule where you drag groups over to rooms and assign time for those groups. Daytime is divided to 10 min entries.

Now what i want is that when you are dragging group above room, i want to highling those 10 min entries that would be covered by group. Same as in fullcalendar when you drag multi-day event.
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

I am using backbone and for drag&drop i use jQuery UI. I don't want to create 10 min droppables because there will be lot of rooms and performance will go down i suppose. Room is not getting mousemove event cause of dragging.

Any ideas, how could room View track the position of dragged group?

Comment: Found solution in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16282228/2732967)